# Copying memory-mapped blocks of memory without intermediate storage in .NET

Tags: .net, memory, xamarin.android

I am looking to implement a custom binary file format that should work on **both** Android (via Xamarin) and Windows. Code is in C# (for Xamarin) and VB.NET (for Windows). I would like to use MemoryMappedFile's and luckily they are supported on both platforms and will fit my needs just fine.

My question: when I need to move data how can I **efficiently** copy page-sized (4KB) blocks of data from one view into another view?

By **efficient** I mean I want to avoid doing a manual byte-by-byte copy in a loop or having to allocate an intermediate buffer into which I read data from the source page and from which I write data into the target page.

Essentially I am looking for a managed version of the Windows [CopyMemory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366535(v=vs.85).aspx) function that will work on Windows and Android/Xamarin (**for extra points, if the solution can work with VB.NET by avoiding/wrapping C# unsafe code that would be awesome**).

Can it be done?

Comment: The question doesn't make any sense, memory access efficiency is dominated by the processor caches.  Which are not page size oriented, the unit of storage for the L1 cache is 64 bytes for example.  Any half-decent memory copy primitive just makes sure that it can make 8-byte aligned copies.  Just focus on finding one, like [Buffer.MemoryCopy()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.memorycopy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: @HansPassant thank's for the pointer to the Buffer class, looks like it will do the trick!